# Extract value from a promise javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, promise, mocha.js, chai

I read documentation about Promise javascript, and it seems not writeable or configurable. But I just want to get the value from it, for example, I have this code:

```
driver.wait(function(){
   return driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(currentUrl) {
      return currentUrl.toLowerCase() == myStringUrl.toLowerCase();
   });
}, 50000);
```

So, currentUrl is a 'promise', and definitely `currentUrl.toLowerCase()` is wrong. But can I do something like this with a 'promise'?

Comment: console.log(currentUrl) returns a promise object, not the value i want like 'http://.....'

Comment: What if you log `console.log(arguments)` ?

Comment: ok, so console.log(currentUrl) returns exactly 'http://......', but, not only one, it's a list of same value 'http://.......'